# How to read float type numbers with special characters from a file

Tags: c, special-characters, scanf

I want to read a float type number from a txt file like this:

```
American history 91 12.9% 8 1
```

But if I read with

```
fscanf(file, "%s %d %f %d %d", major, &number1, &percentage, &number2, &number3);
```

it gives me an error since there is a special character involved. What should I do to just take out only the float part?

Comment: What/where is that 'special character'?

Comment: If you want to capture the `%` you need to read the percentage as a string `%s` in your format string.

Answer (score 2):

It's not failing because of the percent sign, but because your format string is wrong. `%s` doesn't read an arbitrary string, it reads characters up to the first whitespace, i.e. "American". `fscanf` will fail after that. Hint: look up `[`.

To get past the `%` though, all you need to do is have this in your format string: `%f%%` (read a float, match a `%`).

Answer (score 1):

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> **%**
>
> Matches a literal '%'. That is, %% in the format string matches a single input '%' character. No conversion is done (but initial white space characters are discarded), and assignment does not occur.

---

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a, b;
    scanf("%f%%%f", &a, &b);
    printf("%f, %f\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc test.c && echo "1.2%3.4" | ./a.out
1.200000, 3.400000
```

Answer (score 0):

use backslash() as an escape character

> fscanf(file, "%s %d %f\% %d %d", major, &number1, &percentage, &number2, &number3);